# React: Unexpected token import when running npm start

Tags: reactjs, heroku, babeljs

I have a React project that works locally when I open its path in chrome. However, when trying to deploy to Heroku (or running `npm start`), I get this error:

```
import React from 'react';
^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

I've scoured StackOverflow and Heroku's support page to no avail.

Here's my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "my-app-name",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "webpack": "webpack",
    "start": "node ./my-app-name.jsx",
    "postinstall": "webpack"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.24.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.24.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.4.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.23.0",
    "react": "^15.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.2",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.3",
    "react-router": "^4.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.0.0",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "webpack": "^2.3.2"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "6.2.1",
    "npm": "4.4.4"
  }
}
```

And my webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: "./my-app-name.jsx",
  output: {
    filename: "./bundle.js"
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: [/\.jsx?$/, /\.js?$/],
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015', 'react']
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  resolve: {
    extensions: ["*",".js", ".jsx" ]
  }
};
```

My node and npm versions are the same as listed in package.json. I've triple checked to make sure everything is installed correctly and none of the other StackOverflow answers have helped. Surely it has to be some sort of issue with Babel (due to it not recognizing `import`) but I just can't figure out what it is.

Answer (score 0):

`my-app-name.jsx` is not the transpiled build. Instead of `node ./my-app-name.jsx`, you need to point Node to start the transpiled build like this `node ./bundle.js`

Comment: I changed it to `node ./bundle.js` and now I'm getting a `ReferenceError: document is not defined`  in my bundle on  `document.addEventListener`

Comment: I suspect the code is not running in a browser environment. Perhaps a github repo so I can help you further?

Comment: if you need to support both browsers and node js, you will either have to structure your code differently, to target each environment, or even just wrap environment specific functions with conditional checks, this also might be useful: https://www.npmjs.com/package/is-dom